# PHP to write Tab Characters inside a file?

Tags: php, string, csv

How do i simply write out a file including real tabs inside? `tab` means real `tab` which is **not the spaces**. How to write the `tab` or what is the character for real `tab`?

For example here:

```
$chunk = "a,b,c";
file_put_contents("chunk.csv",$chunk);
```

What character should i use to get `tabs` instead of `Commas (,)` there?
In the output file, there should be real `tabs` between the seperated words.

- Real Tabs means, **a true wide space we get when we press the `<tab>` key** in a text-editor.

Comment: so you aren't talking about `"\t"`, right?

Comment: I believe he is talking about `"\t"`. Hard to know about it when you haven't used it before. And actually, I think that pressing the tab-key within the string in your code works as well.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Definitely true. But the answers are all about `a space` i think. A real `Tab` should be more wider.

Comment: Dudes, my fault because of bad example above. Because the answers are right and I just only couldn't see the truth as i used 3 characters in group in the example then when i test, the `tab` has only 1 space left. Thats why i wrongly though that is just a single space. So `\t` is right!!

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The tab character is `\t`. Notice the use of `"` instead of `'`.

```
$chunk = "<html>\t<head>\t\t<title>\t</head>";
```

[PHP Strings - Double quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

> If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret
> more escape sequences for special characters:
>
> ...
>
> \t    horizontal tab (HT or 0x09 (9) in ASCII)

---

Also, let me recommend the [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function which is for the purpose of writing CSV files.

Answer (score 17):

Use `\t` and enclose the string with double-quotes:

```
$chunk = "abc\tdef\tghi";
```

Comment: in other words $chunk = 'abc\tdef\tghi'; in single quotes just doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

This should do:

```
$chunk = "abc\tdef\tghi";
```