# Detect tab indent from text file

Tags: php

I am trying to detect the space that is created in a file (file.txt) when the user has pressed the tab key. I can detect everything else but in this case it seems like nothing is there , like a new line without spaces.

```
$file = fopen('file.txt','r');
while ($line = fgets($file)) {

    $space = mb_substr($line, 0, 1, 'utf-8');
    //$tab = ????? 

    if ($space==' ') { /*DO SOMETHING*/ }else{ echo($line); }
    if ($tab) { /*DO SOMETHING ELSE*/ }else{ echo($line); }

}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: It is not understand what do you want to achive. Tab code is `\t`

Comment: The tab character is known as "\t". Look for that, or else look for html character codes.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11055175/2915402) answer.

Comment: The problem is it doesnt give me any character because the file is a plain file without any html elements. I have just 2 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//If you want to try
$line = "Please insert a tab to this string anywhere!"; //Do what i say! :)))

$tab = false;
if (preg_match("/\t/", $line)) {
    $tab = true;
}
var_dump($tab);
```

Comment: It seems like the  "\t" code is not in there . The file i have is a simple .txt file wihout any html in it . Just 2 lines

Comment: It does not matter what kind of file do you use, we parsing all of the lines of that file. Create a blank php file, copy the code of mine into that, **add a tabulator between 2 words in the string**, and run  the code. The output should be true. I've tested.

Comment: Ok finally i got it to work with your method by converting the $line to a string ($line="$line").I dont know why it wasnt already a string but i am just happy it worked . Thank you for your time ! :-)))

Comment: if(stristr($line,"\t")){ $tab=true; }