# Using tabs spacing in php for text file

Tags: php, csv, text-files

I'm reading a CSV file and printing the data from the CSV file to 2 `.txt` files. The output of the text files are as follows

```
John
Georgina,Sinclair,408999703657,cheque,"First National Bank",Fourways,275.00,12/01/2012
Toby,Henderson,401255489873,cheque,"First National Bank",Edenvale,181.03,12/13/2012
```

Here is my code:

```
    $file_handle = fopen("debitorders.csv", "r") or die("can't open debitorders.csv");
    $absaFile = fopen("ABSA.txt", "w") or die("can't open ABSA.txt");
    $firstNationalBankFile = fopen("First National Bank.txt", "w") or die("can't open First       National Bank.txt");  

    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

        $debitorders = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024, ",");

        if ($debitorders[4] == "ABSA"){
            print_r ($debitorders[4] . "<br />");
            fputcsv($absaFile, $debitorders);

            $ABSA_bank = "ABSA";
            fopen("ABSA.txt", "a");
            file_put_contents('ABSA.txt', $ABSA_bank, FILE_APPEND);
        }

        if ($debitorders[4] == "First National Bank"){
            $FNB_bank = "First National Bank";

            print_r ($debitorders[4] . "<br />");
            fputcsv($firstNationalBankFile, $debitorders);

            $FNB_bank = "First National Bank";
            fopen("First National Bank.txt", "a");
            file_put_contents('First National Bank.txt', $FNB_bank, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    fclose($absaFile);
    fclose($firstNationalBankFile);
```

How can I put tab spaces in the output file instead of commas, so that the output instead looks like this:

```
John
GeorginaSinclair    408999703657  cheque  First National Bank  Fourways 275.0012/01/2012
TobyHenderson       401255489873  cheque  First National Bank  Edenvale 181.0312/13/2012
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: You can do it with `\t` at the end of your string.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055153/php-to-write-tab-characters-inside-a-file

Comment: You want to replace all instances of a comma with a tab before writing it into any of the files.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a while back although it was the other way around. I replaced tabs with commas. Here is the code I used:

```
preg_replace('/[ ]{2,}|[\t]/', ',', $string);
```

The code above removed two tabs and replaced with one comma. So maybe try it this way:

```
preg_replace(',', '/[ ]{1,}|[\t]/', $string);
```

Answer (score -1):

As per [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

```
int fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' ]] )
```

So you can try

```
 fputcsv($absaFile, $debitorders ,"\t");
```